# Visual basic 6 and isDate in bulgarian

Tags: vb6

has anyone used IsDate in bulgarian reginal settings with VB6?

For example today is "11.6.2013 г."

```
IsDate("11.6.2013 г.")
```

returns error.

Any help?

Comment: Is `"11.6.2013 г."` the exact string returned from `CStr(Data)`? `IsDate()` should always recognise the current locale.

Comment: there's a text box: txtBox.text = Date then later on if IsDate(txtBox.text) then... this gives me errors

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance here, but what does the `г.` do on the end of the string?

Comment: It is the date as shown when using bulgarian regional settings in windows xp

Comment: This is a known bug. A workaround is to change short-date format in regional settings. In commercial products I'm hooking `GetLocaleInfo` API call (as imported by `Oleaut32.dll`, `comctl32.dll`, etc.) instead, but this is harder to implement.

Comment: @wqw - do you have any references to support your theory that this is a known bug?

Comment: @MattWilko I mean it's known by every Bulgarian developer (at least), can't point a KB article describing it.